# Info Window doesn't display

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps

In spite of the fact that this question has been asked on Stackoverflow multiple number of times, I haven't been able to implement a working solution to my problem.

I create an array for each parameter associated with a location. My intention is to declare these variables as global variables.

```
var locationid = []
var latitude = []
var longitude = []
var observationdate = []
```

Then I loop through a datadump dictionary object which creates a row in the database for each location on the map with the values in columns being the values of parameters like longitude, latitude etc.

```
        {% for data in datadump %}
            locationid.push('{{data.locationid}}');       
            latitude.push('{{data.latitude}}');
            longitude.push('{{data.longitude}}');
            observationdate.push('{{data.observationdate}}');
        {% endfor %}
```

Next I loop through the database to create a marker at each location and also icon with a .svg static file for all locations.

```
{% for data in datadump %}

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng('{{data.latitude}}','{{data.longitude}}');

var icon = {
    url: "{% static 'darkskymap/img/rocket-15.svg' %}", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20), // scaled size
           };


marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latLng,
map: map,
title: '{{data.locationid}}',
label: '{{data.observationdate}}',
icon: icon
                               });

{% endfor %}
```

Then I declare an infowindow variable and assign it a text content.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Site Observation'
        });
```

And in the last step, I add an on-click listener function that should open the infowindow when the user clicks on the marker.

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
```

The above code generates the markers but no Infowindows are displayed. I have tried to displace the variable declaration for Infowindow, addListener attribute and open methods within the for loop but that generates only one infowindow i.e. the last element in the loop but not the others. So I separated them from the loop to achieve loop closure, but that doesn't solve the problem. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, make sure you have `infowindow` and the `infowindow` event listener in the same for loop as the one in which you are defining markers. Also for code clarity and keeping track of markers add `forloop.counter` to each `latLng`, `marker`, `icon` and `infowindow` so that they are numbered.

Here is the code for reference.

```
{% for data in datadump %}

    // latLng for the marker
    var latLng{{forloop.counter}} = new google.maps.LatLng('{{data.latitude}}','{{data.longitude}}');

    // icon for marker.
    var icon{{forloop.counter}} = {
        url: "{% static 'darkskymap/img/rocket-15.svg' %}", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20), // scaled size
    };

    // add the marker.
    marker{{forloop.counter}} = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng{{forloop.counter}},
        map: map,
        title: '{{data.locationid}}',
        label: '{{data.observationdate}}',
        icon: icon{{forloop.counter}}
    });

    // create the infowindow for the marker.
    var infowindow{{forloop.counter}} = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Site Observation'
    });  

    // add event listener to open infowindow for the marker.
    marker{{forloop.counter}}.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow{{forloop.counter}}.open(map, marker{{forloop.counter}});
    });    

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this instead:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
})
```

That is the proper way to add an event to a marker. I am also noticing that you are looping to create multiple markers, and i a, assuming they all will have an infowindow. You'll want to keep track of them and associate the infowindows with their marker.

Comment: A huge thank you Devin. Atleast you tried to help instead of downvoting my question. I copy-pasted your code to perform the on-click event listener function. Unfortunately it doesn't work. The infowindows don't appear. Once an infowindow appears, I will then adapt the content of each window to be unique to each marker. I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: My javascript code contains a jinja for loop which Codepen identifies as an error. I am not sure if sharing on codepen would help. Can I send my html file by email or private message ? I am a complete novice at programming.

Comment: maybe sure you are importing all of the resources necessary for the environment. I can't be much help in that regard, at least not without a decent time investment, since I'm no django expert.

Comment: After fumbling around on Codepen for an hour, I haven't figured out how to import Django ressources into the codepen environment. Importing .js & .css ressources seems possible but haven't found a workable solution for Django. I will have to find another way to solve this problem. Thanks a lot for your help anyways Devin.